# TCP Server application becomes unresponsive

Tags: java, tcp, tcpserver

I was trying to make a `TCP` GUI Server application for windows. But when i am trying to start the server it becomes unresponsive. I couldn't find out what is the problem here,somebody please give me a good solution for this bug...

**code**

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;


public class frame_example extends JFrame{


    private static ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private static Socket clientSocket;
    private static InputStreamReader inputStreamReader;
    private static BufferedReader bufferedReader;
    private static String message;
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public frame_example(){
        //JFrame jf = new JFrame();
        JPanel jp = new JPanel();
        final JTextArea jt  = new JTextArea(10,20);
        JScrollPane scrolltxt = new JScrollPane(jt);
        scrolltxt.setBounds(0,0, 300, 200);
        //add(scrolltxt);
        JButton jb1 = new JButton("START");
        jb1.setActionCommand("Server Started..");
        JButton jb2 = new JButton("STOP");
        jb2.setActionCommand("Server has been Stoped..");

        jp.add(scrolltxt);
        jp.add(jb1);
        jp.add(jb2);
        getContentPane().add(jp);
        jb1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                   try {
                        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4020);  //Server socket

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        System.out.println("Could not listen on port: 4020");
                    }

        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(20);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {

                clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();   //accept the client connection
                inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream());
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader); //get the client message
                message = bufferedReader.readLine();
 if(message.equals("shutdown")){

Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process proc = runtime.exec("shutdown -s -t 00");
System.exit(0);

 }
 else if(message.equals("restart")){
Runtime runtime1 = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process proc2 = runtime1.exec("shutdown -r -t 00");
System.exit(0);


 }

                //System.out.println(message);


            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Problem in message reading");
            }
        }   
            }
        });
jb2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {

                    inputStreamReader.close();
                    clientSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });


    }
    public static void main(String args[]){

        frame_example fe = new frame_example();

        fe.setSize(400, 200);
        fe.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: As an aside, the poor formatting of your code makes it *really* hard to read - I'd initially mistaken the loop as being inside the constructor itself rather than in the action listener. Please put more effort into formatting your code readably in future questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I couldn't find out what is the problem here

Well, you've got this code executing *in your UI thread*:

```
while (true) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(20);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        clientSocket = serverSocket.accept(); 
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

So when you start your UI, it is basically hanging the UI thread. You can't block the UI thread like this - it should be in a separate thread, marshalling over to the UI thread when necessary (to update the UI).

See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details of the threading rules of swing.